# How does "Implement interface through <field>" work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I'm wondering how the *"Implement interface through [field]"* thing works with Intellisense, is it something that's just hard-coded into Intellisense for specific interfaces, or is it done dynamically? If so, is there a way I can get it to do the same thing with my own interfaces?

Note: I looked through many similar questions, and I think that by now it's safe to assume that nobody has asked the question I'm trying to ask. I also cannot think of any ways to make it any less ambiguous.

Comment: ...Again I end up in a situation where I have to question why I didn't try what should've been obvious at the time first. I'll try that and see if it works the way I expected it would.

Comment: It's completely fine to ask questions that you could answer yourself by trying things out. Don't let SO's community tell you otherwise. At this rate, no one would ever ask any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is pretty straightforward. If you have a class that meets these criteria:

- claims to implement an interface
- isn't implementing the members required by that interface
- has a field or a property which *does* implement that interface

... then this code analysis recommendation will allow you to create implementations for the missing members which simply pass through to the same members on the given field or property.

You can absolutely make it work on your own interface, by meeting the aforementioned criteria.

[image: before]

[image: after]